# SQL Server 2008R2 alter GETDATE result as a default value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, getdate

Is there a way to alter the outcome of `getdate()` while still using it as a default value?  E.g. being able to plus or minus x number of hours.

The situation:

a German hosted server (GMT+2) with some end users in Australia (GMT+10). One column is using the default `getdate()` value therefore is inserting German time. Some code is generating a `DateTime` based on Australia time so there are 8 hours difference.

The objective:

For several good reasons the aim is to handle this on the database and not touch application code. I would like to add 8 hours onto the German `getdate()` default database value....... or handle this some other way on the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use default value using DATEADD() function to add 8 hours to the date:

```
create table dbo.foo
(
dateColumn datetime default (dateadd(hour,8,getdate()))
)
```

Comment: Thank you.   I must have had an error in my attempt at this because yours does work without issue.    This said, given the day light savings we have here this approach is not going to be 100%.......

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any such option and it is little dangerous too. You can create a function with the same name `GETDATE` in your database, but that would require you to prefix with dbo(or schema name) while calling the function.

So, you may need to write your own function and make use of [GETUTCDATE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx) and add delta according to timezone.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.  As I have said below in response to Harsh, I must have had an error in my attempt at his solution because his does work without issue.  What would the danger be in using this approach?